# Glass development kit preview installed but not found in Android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

[screenshot from problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xNu7.png)

I don't understand what is causing this problem. I have tried to search all over internet for solutions, but nothing seems to work. I wonder could this 3.0 have something to do with it? Anyone has idea what is problem?

Comment: Came to mind, what was last android studio build, where gdk worked. If I install it instead and try if it works.

Comment: Is 4.4 the last API version with the Glass Development Kit in it?

Comment: yes it is and only one also

Comment: That's insane to me. But thanks for letting me know. They've really abandoned this platform, even though they're bringing it out for their "Enterprise Edition" release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Open settings (CMD +,)
2. Type "path"
3. Add the path to the glass folder explicitly
   (EG: pathToAndroidSdk/.m2/repository/glassStuff)

[image: add a variable here]

Comment: only place where I found stuff for glass, was at add-ons folder. I tried to put many different paths to there and inside some folders in gdk folder, but didn't work.

Comment: Usually sdk manager puts things in Android/sdk/extras/Android

Comment: Looks like it works at path I found to gdk file. I started my pc again for other reason, then continued with this problem but problem was gone. Tested could this solve my problem by creating another glass app, same problem, but problem was gone after restart whole pc. So for now I go with this solve until it doesn't work.